# Is it possible to sell a Windows 10/11 retail licence once it's no longer needed? What steps are required?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, license, windows-activation

If I am going to pay US$199 for a Windows 10/11 Professional Retail licence, I'd like to know that it has some kind of resale value should I decide to switch to Linux or decommission the PC.

Is it possible (and legal) to sell the retail licence key once it's no longer needed?

If so, what steps would be required on behalf of the seller and buyer to ensure it's properly transferred?

Microsoft has a rather confusing and opaque method of tying licences to some combination of your hardware, but also to your Microsoft.com account for recovery, so how would someone transfer this cleanly?

(This question is specifically about the *Retail* edition of Windows 10 and/or 11, not *OEM* licences, which are specifically for 1 machine only and non-transferable – these have almost no resale value, unless you sell the hardware and OS together as a bundle.)

Comment: The seller would just format the machine linked to the license. If the device was linked to a Microsoft Account, the seller would also remove the device, but that’s an optional step for their sanity. We can’t determine the legality of selling a Windows license. I must point out there isn’t really a marketplace for used Windows licenses.

Comment: Such licenses are not worth very much money. If someone needs a license for their own computer, they can purchase an OEM license from a legitimate dealer.

Answer (score 2):

It would be legal to resell a *retail* Windows 10 license only if you were the first owner of the license, provided you wipe it from the machine where it is installed. Section 4, "Transfer" in the Microsoft License Agreement states:

> b.      Stand-alone software. If you acquired the software as stand-alone software (and also if you upgraded from software you acquired as stand-alone software), you may transfer the software to another device that belongs to you. You may also transfer the software to a device owned by someone else if (i) you are the first licensed user of the software and (ii) the new user agrees to the terms of this agreement. You may use the backup copy we allow you to make or the media that the software came on to transfer the software. Every time you transfer the software to a new device, you must remove the software from the prior device. You may not transfer the software to share licenses between devices.